# RDS instances script automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a bash script that will find my rds instance with a particular tag and stop the instance.
For example, if my rds instance is running with the tag Name=application_name and value=abc, it should provide me the list of the instance and then stop those.

Comment: Ok, but you forgot to provide your bash script and explain what is wrong with it. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I haven't created one :( But as of now I have found this command  
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=application_name -- output table
but i alos need the value=abc as well

Comment: If anyone can give me an idea about how i can start or if there is any already available that would help .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like:

```bash
ID=$(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:instance --tag-filters Key=application_name,Values=abc --output text)

aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier $ID
```

I didn't test it, but that should get you going!

See: [get-resources — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html)

Comment: Thanks @John Rotesnstein. I will test it ..